# How to get the value from slider in other format?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

currently my slider looks like this [image]

I want to change the number of current position in a format without decimal place. So in this case
it should show me 27 instead of 0.2731...

here is my Code

```
@Composable
fun Slider() {
    var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    Slider(value = sliderPosition,
        onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it })
    Text(text = sliderPosition.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to rounded int and then to float

```
Slider(
    value = sliderPosition,
    onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it.roundToInt().toFloat() },
    valueRange = 0f..100f
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Slider has a `valueRange` paremeter which is  valueRange: `ClosedFloatingPointRange<Float> = 0f..1f` by default, you can change it as

`valueRange = 0f..100f` or `valueRange = 0f..360f` or any closed range of your choosing

```
 Slider(
        value = sliderPosition,
        onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it},
        valueRange = 0f..100f
    )
```

Comment: modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), 
I getting an error it says: Unresolved reference: weight 
If I removing it, the new number is 27.9023...

Comment: Sorry, you don't need Modifier.weight(1f).  it's defined in ColumnScope and RowScope. Your Slider should be in Column or Row but for your example it's not necessary. It just covers available space left from Composables with no weight modifier or partition space with the ones that have weight modifier. Edited my answer.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with the slider. I have it set to a range of 1f..8f and the steps are set to 8. For some reason, it is not giving me whole numbers, is this a bug, or am I missing something? @Thracian

Comment: @VirtualProdigy The documentation is really poor here, but steps should `= (max - min)/steps-1`, so for your example of `1f..8f` with integer steps, that's `(8 - 1)/1 - 1) = 6`